# php strip_tags and preserve separation

Tags: php

I would like to parse this:

```
<p>
  Text1
  <b>Text2 Text3</b>
  Text4
<p><br>
Text5
```

Into this array:

```
[
  "Text1", 
  "Text2 Text3", 
  "Text4", 
  "Text5"
]
```

Currently I am using `strip_tags` but this provides the less detailed:

```
"Text1 Text2 Text3 Text4 Text5"
```

What is a better approach to get the desired result?

*My application is email processing. I'd like to do a little digraph and trigraph analysis but do not want to pick up graphs across HTML element boundaries.*

Comment: why not use `explode(' ', "Text1 Text2 Text3 Text4");` after you get that string?

Comment: So every newline should be its own value in an array? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2447ab520282c23f7258dbc6a9eb680c4d0f4b14

Comment: @iam-decoder Sorry for the confusion, I have updated the question to include an example ("Text 2 Text3") which I would not like to be separated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use tags as delimeters for split, trim result and remove empty strings

```
$array = array_filter(array_map('trim', preg_split('/<[^>]+>/', $str)));
```

result

```
Array (
    [1] => Text1
    [2] => Text2 Text3
    [3] => Text4
    [5] => Text5 )
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the perfect piece of clever thinking that I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

when you get the result as,

```
$result="Text1 Text2 Text3 Text4";

$finalarray=explode(' ',$result);
```

gives your final required array.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have updated the question to include an example ("Text 2 Text3") which I would not like to be separated